# Running protractor in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, firefox, protractor

I tried to run protractor tests in firefox, but unfortunately with no luck. Tests run correctly on chrome, but firefox doesn't know how to start a page. Every time it tries to go to an url it throws incorrect url: `about:blank&utm_content=firstrun`.

My config is pretty simple:

```
exports.config = {
  multiCapabilities: [{
         'browserName': 'firefox'
         }, {
         'browserName': 'chrome'
     }],
  },

  params: {
     url: 'https://google.com/',
     outdir: './test/coverage/',
     elements: [{
     'type': 'button',
     'events': ['click'],
     'elements': []
     }],
 },
  onPrepare: function() {
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter.getJasmine2Reporter());

  /*Logging*/
},

 framework: 'jasmine',
 seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
```

I tried it on firefox version 48

Comment: What version of firefox do you have ?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: I get the same thing and I'm using Firefox 49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a compatibility issue with Firefox & Selenium 
The source of truth for all compatibility info is [Selenium ChangeLog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG#L49)

The last compatibility declaration was in Selenium 2.51 changeLog and it reads s below. So once downgrade firefox to 46/45/44 and it should be seamless

> In keeping with project support policy for Firefox, This driver    has
>   been tested with Firefox 44 (current release), 43 (immediately prior
>   release), 38 (current ESR release), and 31 (immediately prior ESR
>   release).

Comment: I tried it on 44 and it works. It loads correct url, but fails because timeout, but this is an issue on my side, because I have to play with default timeout options. Anyway thank you.